# Wordpress PHP Variable with multiple values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building an archive page in WordPress that is pulling content from certain page IDs. Is there a way to create a variable that would go in place of 266 in the code below so I don't have to recreate this code for each ID?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom">
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( 266 ); ?>">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="<?php the_field('photo', 266); ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h4><?php echo get_the_title( 266 ); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you code in a function and place that function to functions.php
and just call that function instead of recreating code again.

E.g.

functions.php

```
<?php
function your_function_name( $page_id ) {
    if ( ! $page_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $content = '<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="ih-item square effect6 from_top_and_bottom">
            <a href="' . get_the_permalink( $page_id ) . '">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="' . the_field('photo', $page_id) . '" />
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h4>' . get_the_title( $page_id ) . '</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>';

    return $content
}
?>
```

archive.php

```
<?php echo your_function_name( 266 ); ?>
```